# Python float formatting - like "g", but with more digits

Tags: python, formatting, floating-point

I use `"g"` for formatting floating point values, but it switches to scientific formatting too soon for me - at the 5th digit:

```
>>> format(0.0001, "g")
'0.0001'
>>> format(0.00001, "g")
'1e-05'
```

This seems to be described in the `"g"` rules (the -4):

> The precise rules are as follows: suppose that the result formatted with presentation type 'e' and precision p-1 would have exponent exp. Then if -4 <= exp < p, the number is formatted with presentation type 'f' and precision p-1-exp. Otherwise, the number is formatted with presentation type 'e' and precision p-1. In both cases insignificant trailing zeros are removed from the significand, and the decimal point is also removed if there are no remaining digits following it.

Is there a way to display numbers like `"g"`, but with more digits before switching to scientific notation?

I'm thinking of using `".6f"` and stripping trailing zeros, but then I won't be able to see small numbers, which need scientific notation.

Comment: as per a comment below, `".6g"` is valid format string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from math import log10

if log10(n) < -5:
    print "%e" % n
else:
    print "%f" % n
```

EDIT: it's also possible to put it on a single line:

```
("%e" if log10(n) < -5 else "%f") % n
```

If n might be negative, then use `log10(abs(n))` in place of `log10(n)`.

EDIT 2: Improved based on Adal's comments:

```
"%e" % n if n and log10(abs(n)) < -5 else ("%f" % n).rstrip("0")
```

This will print 0 as "0."--if you want another representation like "0" or "0.0", you'll need to special case it with a separate `if`.

Comment: +1 - or, as a one-liner: `(('%f','%e')[log10(n) < -5]) % n` - however, the solution works with positive `n` only.

Comment: @eumiro: Good point on the negative numbers (updated the answer), but I don't really like your one liner. Indexing a tuple by boolean values is just...non-pythonic.

Comment: .rstrip("0") should be added to the "%f" output, so that the result more resembles "%g"

Comment: a check for n == 0 is also needed (log not defined for 0)

Answer (score 10):

I had the same question.

Looking at the *Python* documentation it seems that **g** also supports precision values:

> General format. For a given precision *p >= 1*, this rounds the
>   number to **p** significant digits and then formats the result in
>   either fixed-point format or in scientific notation, depending on its
>   magnitude.

I don't know, why the other answers don't use this and I am not very experienced in *Python*, but it works.

This can be simply achieved by using `format(0.00001, '.10g')` where 10 is the precision you want.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I find some of the more obscure string formatting poorly documented or hard to find. This works for me where I'm using pandas to create a csv: `dataframe.to_csv(float_format="%.12g")`

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how g with precision works: 
f"{10.554545:2g}" -> '10.5545'
f"{10.554545:.2g}" -> '11'
f"{10.554500:2g}" -> '10.5545'
f"{10.554500:3g}" -> '10.5545'
f"{10.554500:10g}" -> '   10.5545'
So it seems it's not really precision.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to include a point after the colon for several examples? Or was that just for testing purposes? I think the point is needed and when it is there, it does what is expected: It turns `10.554545` into `11` (two significant digits). `f"{10.554545:.4g}"` will probably result in `10.55`.

I haven't tried, though, this is just my assumption.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Python 2.7 you can do the following using it's advanced string formatting [mini-language](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```
>>> '{number:.{width}f}'.format(number=0.000000000001, width=20)
'0.00000000000100000000'
```

You can then specify the required value of `number` and `width` dynamically.

Comment: I still want to keep exponential notation for small numbers like 1e-25, and not display 0.0000000000 instead

Answer (score -1):

try:
if abs(log10(n)) >= 5:
pass
#print("Number N is :","%e" % n)
#else:
#    print("Number N is :","%f" % n)
except ValueError:
print("Number N is :","%e" % n)
else:
if abs(log10(E)) >= 5:
print("Number N is :","%e" % n)
else:
print("Number N is :","%f" % n)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).